# Include other parameters in permalinks for better management of browser history

Tags: permalinks, jquery, ajax

In single.php, I have the following items that I manage (create, update, hide) with jquery/ajax:

- a `<select>` tag in which I return all website categories.
- a second `<select>` tag in which I return post titles depending on
  the selected category in first `<select>` tag.
- a `<div>` tag which contains a content based on the selected post
  in second `<select>`. This content is divided into tabs. On click on
  a tab, I display via ajax a meta value of the custom field related to
  this tab for the specific post selected in second `<select>` . In
  addition, I am making a jquery pagination system for each tab whenever the
  meta value is long.

All jquery/ ajax actions are working like a charm respecting all rules of DOM updating and scripts reloading after triggering actions on updated DOM.

In sum, I have 4 parameters while navigating in single.php:

- current category of post (returned by php).
- current post id (returned automatically since we are in single.php).
- current tab.
- current page inside tab.

The problem is that I am actually including `history.js` to my website so that I can manage the history stack and the clicks on browser back-forward buttons.

Actually, the only URL structure I am having is:

```
mywebsite.com/?p=post_id
```

As you know, Wordpress allows navigating between posts by only changing `p` parameter, so this url structure is maintained during all navigation. And inside each post page, I can do further navigation via AJAX, but keeping the same post permalink in adress bar, which is not good for history management, SEO, bookmarking.....

How can I add the other 2 last parameters (current tab, current page) in an efficient way so that my URLs become like:

```
mywebsite.com/?p=post_id&tab=tab_number&pagi=pagi_number
```

Doing so, I think I can perform conditionnal tests inside `History.Adapter.bind(window, 'statechange', function() {}` so that I run history actions based on the values of the 3 parameters (current post_id, current_tab and current_page).

Do you have an idea or a better approach for doing such?

Making my website full jquery-ajaxified, respecting history and using wordpress is an issue that I am digging to resolve for a long time. Your help is really appreciated.

Comment: We don't need a tag for a topic with just _one_ question. :)

Comment: are you sure sir ? why not to make a test by creating this tag and give some time to check how many beginner are asking how many questions about Wordpress and history.js

Comment: Tags exists to group questions by concepts. Anyway, this belongs to [meta].

Comment: @lettersandblankspaces Please go through all questions, collect the ones that refer to the use of history.js, then add a question on Meta containing all those links. If you got more than 5, we will add it. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: aaah thanks kaiser, now I understand the procedure.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? I'm reading it and I'm following a train of thought then you suddenly announce a new piece of information as if something else was wrong and then ... *confused*, please cleanup. State clearly and definitively: What you have, What you tried, What the problem is, What an answer would need to do, because it's very hard to follow at the moment

Comment: @Tom J Nowell  I will do a cleanup for my question. Thank your for your time and remarks.

Comment: Also, I have a suspicion that this is purely a JS problem, and if so this is offtopic, but I can't decipher what it is you're asking yet so who knows

Comment: I hope my edit is fitting now with the requirements, also I think it is a PHP/Core Wordpress/JS problem.